# External and internal storage how to check both

Tags: android

I get the difference between the two but is there a way to see the internal storage file? Because I want to check if the file is like I want it to be.

Then I created a external file and when I'm programming in eclipse and I test my app the file is created and I can see it on my phone via a filemanager but when I browse via my windows explorer to the HTC memory the file isn't there. Is this because I'm working in eclipse and this is debug? Or is there a way to check the file on my computer?

Thanks already

Comment: # adb shell, cd (/mnt/sdcard/ ; /data/data/app package/), ls

Comment: Thanks. Also I openend the window "file explorer" in eclipse and then I can see the file but not open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public static String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + your folder path

it give a path of your memory storage either it is internal or external it give

Answer (score 0):

Bhanu Sharma solution works. For the external file there is in eclipse a nice way.
Open the file explorer window in eclipse and then you can click a file and right above there are icons to push and pull the file to your device. ;-)